# fix compile errors of typescript from 2.1.XX to 2.4.XXX

Tags: typescript

I have migrated my project from typescript 2.1.XX version to 2.4.2. The file below is a jhipster generated and its giving me the error when i compile file:

> error TS2345: Argument of type '() => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IServiceProvider'.
>     Property '$get' is missing in type '() => void'.

Can you please help me identify what is causing the compile error.

```
  namespace module.system {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module(module.appName)
       .provider('AlertService', AlertService);

    function AlertService () {
        this.toast = false;
        /*jshint validthis: true */
        this.$get = getService;

        this.showAsToast = function(isToast) {
            this.toast = isToast;
        };

        getService.$inject = ['$timeout', '$sce'];

        function getService ($timeout, $sce) {
            let toast = this.toast,
                alertId = 0, // unique id for each alert. Starts from 0.
                alerts = [],
                timeout = 5000; // default timeout

            return {
                factory: factory,
                isToast: isToast,
                add: addAlert,
                closeAlert: closeAlert,
                closeAlertByIndex: closeAlertByIndex,
                clear: clear,
                get: get,
                success: success,
                error: error,
                info: info,
                warning : warning
            };

            function isToast() {
                return toast;
            }

            function clear() {
                alerts = [];
            }

            function get() {
                return alerts;
            }

            function success(msg, params, position) {
                return this.add({
                    type: 'success',
                    msg: msg,
                    params: params,
                    timeout: timeout,
                    toast: toast,
                    position: position
                });
            }

            function error(msg, params, position) {
                return this.add({
                    type: 'danger',
                    msg: msg,
                    params: params,
                    timeout: timeout,
                    toast: toast,
                    position: position
                });
            }

            function warning(msg, params, position) {
                return this.add({
                    type: 'warning',
                    msg: msg,
                    params: params,
                    timeout: timeout,
                    toast: toast,
                    position: position
                });
            }

            function info(msg, params, position) {
                return this.add({
                    type: 'info',
                    msg: msg,
                    params: params,
                    timeout: timeout,
                    toast: toast,
                    position: position
                });
            }

            function factory(alertOptions) {
                let alert = {
                    type: alertOptions.type,
                    msg: $sce.trustAsHtml(alertOptions.msg),
                    id: alertOptions.alertId,
                    timeout: alertOptions.timeout,
                    toast: alertOptions.toast,
                    position: alertOptions.position ? alertOptions.position : 'top right',
                    scoped: alertOptions.scoped,
                    close: function (alerts) {
                        return closeAlert(this.id, alerts);
                    }
                };
                if(!alert.scoped) {
                    alerts.push(alert);
                }
                return alert;
            }

            function addAlert(alertOptions, extAlerts) {
                alertOptions.alertId = alertId++;
                let that = this;
                let alert = this.factory(alertOptions);
                if (alertOptions.timeout && alertOptions.timeout > 0) {
                    $timeout(function () {
                        that.closeAlert(alertOptions.alertId, extAlerts);
                    }, alertOptions.timeout);
                }
                return alert;
            }

            function closeAlert(id, extAlerts) {
                let thisAlerts = extAlerts ? extAlerts : alerts;
                return closeAlertByIndex(thisAlerts.map(function(e) { return e.id; }).indexOf(id), thisAlerts);
            }

            function closeAlertByIndex(index, thisAlerts) {
                return thisAlerts.splice(index, 1);
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how this code successfully compiled before, but I can see the problem now.  If you jump to the declaration of the `provider` method in your IDE (or view the declaration online [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/3db545b2e2ec38fc3f6dce1dc8fcd5f386b864e6/types/angular/index.d.ts#L255)), you'll see that `provider` requires either an `IServiceProviderFactory` (a function that returns an `IServiceProvider` object) or an `IServiceProviderClass` (a class / constructor function that extends `IServiceProvider`), where in each case, an `IServiceProvider` object is one that has, at a minimum, a `$get` property.  It looks like your `AlertService` is intended to be a constructor function, but TypeScript doesn't recognize it as such.  (In `.ts` files, TypeScript only recognizes classes as constructable.  There are some special cases for `.js` files.)

The easy way out is to use a type assertion on the argument to `provider`.  This won't check that `AlertService` is a valid `IServiceProvider` constructor function, but it might be your best option if the `AlertService` code is automatically generated and you want to minimize the amount of patching you have to do to it.

```
// In TypeScript 3.0 or newer, you can replace `any` with `unknown`.
angular
    .module(module.appName)
   .provider('AlertService', <angular.IServiceProviderClass><any>AlertService);
```

Alternatively, you could convert `AlertService` to a real class.  The following should work if I haven't made any mistakes:

```
namespace module.system {
    "use strict";

    class AlertService {
        toast = false;
        $get($timeout, $sce) {
            let toast = this.toast,
                alertId = 0, // unique id for each alert. Starts from 0.
                alerts = [],
                timeout = 5000; // default timeout

            return {
                factory: factory,
                isToast: isToast,
                add: addAlert,
                closeAlert: closeAlert,
                closeAlertByIndex: closeAlertByIndex,
                clear: clear,
                get: get,
                success: success,
                error: error,
                info: info,
                warning : warning
            };

            function isToast() {
                return toast;
            }

            function clear() {
                alerts = [];
            }

            function get() {
                return alerts;
            }

            function success(msg, params, position) {
                return this.add({
                    type: 'success',
                    msg: msg,
                    params: params,
                    timeout: timeout,
                    toast: toast,
                    position: position
                });
            }

            function error(msg, params, position) {
                return this.add({
                    type: 'danger',
                    msg: msg,
                    params: params,
                    timeout: timeout,
                    toast: toast,
                    position: position
                });
            }

            function warning(msg, params, position) {
                return this.add({
                    type: 'warning',
                    msg: msg,
                    params: params,
                    timeout: timeout,
                    toast: toast,
                    position: position
                });
            }

            function info(msg, params, position) {
                return this.add({
                    type: 'info',
                    msg: msg,
                    params: params,
                    timeout: timeout,
                    toast: toast,
                    position: position
                });
            }

            function factory(alertOptions) {
                let alert = {
                    type: alertOptions.type,
                    msg: $sce.trustAsHtml(alertOptions.msg),
                    id: alertOptions.alertId,
                    timeout: alertOptions.timeout,
                    toast: alertOptions.toast,
                    position: alertOptions.position ? alertOptions.position : 'top right',
                    scoped: alertOptions.scoped,
                    close: function (alerts) {
                        return closeAlert(this.id, alerts);
                    }
                };
                if(!alert.scoped) {
                    alerts.push(alert);
                }
                return alert;
            }

            function addAlert(alertOptions, extAlerts) {
                alertOptions.alertId = alertId++;
                let that = this;
                let alert = this.factory(alertOptions);
                if (alertOptions.timeout && alertOptions.timeout > 0) {
                    $timeout(function () {
                        that.closeAlert(alertOptions.alertId, extAlerts);
                    }, alertOptions.timeout);
                }
                return alert;
            }

            function closeAlert(id, extAlerts) {
                let thisAlerts = extAlerts ? extAlerts : alerts;
                return closeAlertByIndex(thisAlerts.map(function(e) { return e.id; }).indexOf(id), thisAlerts);
            }

            function closeAlertByIndex(index, thisAlerts) {
                return thisAlerts.splice(index, 1);
            }
        }
    }
    AlertService.prototype.$get.$inject = ['$timeout', '$sce'];

    angular
        .module(module.appName)
       .provider('AlertService', AlertService);
}
```

As an aside, I'd urge you to upgrade to the latest version of TypeScript (currently 3.1.4) if you can.  Improvements are being made all the time, including improvements to error messages that might help you correct future problems.

Comment: Both solutions did work. Thank you for clearly articulating both solutions. I am still skeptical when it comes to chasing current versions but its a point taken.